# NoMethodError: undefined method `run' for "unit/TestTestName.rb" when running testsuite in ruby

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, jruby, test-suite

I want to write a testsuite to run my unit tests in ruby. So far I have come up with:

```
require 'test/unit/ui/console/testrunner'
require 'test/unit/testsuite'

class RunTests
  def self.Run(arg)
    test_suite = Test::Unit::TestSuite.new("All ATP Tests")
    test_suite << 'unit/TestName1.rb'
    test_suite << 'unit/TestName2.rb'
    test_suite << 'unit/TestName3.rb'

    arg used here in env setup

    Test::Unit::UI::Console::TestRunner::new(test_suite).start
  end

end
```

the tests all have the structure:

```
require 'test/unit'

class TestCalssName < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def setup

  end

  def test_testcasename

  end

  def teardown

  end

end
```

When I test the runner out in irb I get an error about undefined method run within a testcase:

```
irb(main):002:0> RunTests::Run("-env=qa-old")
Loaded suite All ATP Tests
Started


Finished in 0.002 seconds.

0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifications
0% passed

0.00 tests/s, 0.00 assertions/s
NoMethodError: undefined method `run' for "unit/TestTestName.rb":String
from /home/user/.gem/jruby/1.9/gems/test-unit-2.5.5/lib/test/unit/testsuite.rb:121:in `run_test'
from /home/user/.gem/jruby/1.9/gems/test-unit-2.5.5/lib/test/unit/testsuite.rb:53:in `run'
from /home/user/.gem/jruby/1.9/gems/test-unit-2.5.5/lib/test/unit/ui/testrunnermediator.rb:65:in `run_suite'
from /home/user/.gem/jruby/1.9/gems/test-unit-2.5.5/lib/test/unit/ui/testrunnermediator.rb:44:in `run'
from /home/user/.gem/jruby/1.9/gems/test-unit-2.5.5/lib/test/unit/ui/testrunnermediator.rb:100:in `with_listener'
from /home/user/.gem/jruby/1.9/gems/test-unit-2.5.5/lib/test/unit/ui/testrunnermediator.rb:40:in `run'
from /home/user/.gem/jruby/1.9/gems/test-unit-2.5.5/lib/test/unit/ui/testrunner.rb:40:in `start_mediator'
from /home/user/.gem/jruby/1.9/gems/test-unit-2.5.5/lib/test/unit/ui/testrunner.rb:25:in `start'
from /home/user/projects/verizon-smoke-tests/src/main/ruby/unit/RunATP.rb:27:in `Run'
from (irb):2:in `evaluate'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1119:in `eval'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1519:in `loop'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1282:in `catch'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1282:in `catch'
from /usr/local/jruby-1.7.9/bin/irb:13:in `(root)'
irb(main):003:0>
```

I tried putting a run method into the testcases but I still get the error (the exact same error about the run method being undefined). Am I missing something?

A

Answer (score 0):

check if you're not calling `run` instead of `Run`, as Ruby is case-sensitive this might be the problem. We need the source code of "unit/TestTestName.rb" to get a better understanding of the problem.

**EDIT**

You are adding your TestCases as strings, like this :

```
test_suite << 'unit/TestName1.rb'
```

Since `"unit/TestName1.rb"` is a String, it has no `run` method that Ruby can call.
Ruby is expecting `TestSuite` objects in your `test_suite` object instead of Strings.

From Ruby Doc:

> *suite()* :
>   Rolls up all of the test* methods in the fixture into one suite,
>   creating a new instance of the fixture for each method.

Instead, you should:

- `require` on all your `TestNameX.rb` file
- Add each TestCase to your TestSuite using the `suite`

It should be something like this:

```
require 'test/unit/ui/console/testrunner'
require 'test/unit/testsuite'
require 'unit/TestName1.rb'
require 'unit/TestName2.rb'

class RunTests
  def self.Run(arg)
    test_suite = Test::Unit::TestSuite.new("All ATP Tests")
    test_suite << TestClassName1.suite
    test_suite << TestClassName2.suite

    arg used here in env setup

    Test::Unit::UI::Console::TestRunner::new(test_suite).start
  end
end
```

I am not sure about the `TestRunner::new(test_suite).start`, try:

```
Test::Unit::UI::Console::TestRunner.run(test_suite)
```

Feel free to have a look at the Ruby documentation
[Test::Unit Test Suite](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/Test/Unit.html#label-Test+Suite)

Comment: TestTestName.rb has the structure that I outlined above. It does not have a Run method. I was not aware that it needed a run method to include it in a suite

Comment: I don't really know this Testing Framework but it seems like Ruby is trying to call a `run` method on an object that doesn't have it.

Comment: when you require a testcase that inherits test::unit::testcase the testcase is run. I don't want it run by the runner

Comment: It even says it in the documentation that it "Test::Unit is smart enough to find all the test cases existing in the ObjectSpace and wrap them up into a suite for you. It then runs the dynamic suite using the console TestRunner.". This is not what I want. I want to create my own testsuite runner as in the above method the tests are run individually and each test creates its own objects. I want to share objects common to all testcases so this would be easy in my own testsuite